# Unity VideoPlayer lags when playing local file using a url

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am playing a 360 3D video using a skybox.
At first I had the video as an asset and it worked fine, without any lag.

The problem is the video is 7GB and it is not suitable to have it as an asset but it is preferable to store it on the Headset (PICO) and then read it using the url parameter of the VideoPlayer component :

```
videoPlayer5 = GetComponent<VideoPlayer>().gameObject.AddComponent<UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer>();
videoPlayer5.url = @"/storage/self/primary/Android/obb/com.Com.MyCompany.Namespace.Appname\VideoFile.mp4";        
videoPlayer5.renderMode = UnityEngine.Video.VideoRenderMode.RenderTexture;
videoPlayer5.targetTexture = VideoTexture;
videoPlayer5.SetDirectAudioMute(0, true);
```

But by doing so, the video does not play smoothly, it "lags".
Is there any particular reason for this ? Can anything be done to fix that ?

Thank

Comment: Why do you GetComponent VideoPlayer then AddComponent VideoPlayer? GetComponent it self returns VideoPlayer. Also Video is very large 7GB maybe you can optimize lower the resolution, change encoding like webm which is light weight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed the video encoding. Optimizing the video fixed the problem.